# What is the purpose of the capacitor (C97) in between the gate and drain of the p-channel MOSFET in this power control circuit?

Tags: mosfet, capacitor, p-channel

I can't figure out what purpose the capacitor serves.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It slows down the switching of the MOSFET from on to off and vice versa.  Since it is a capacitor fed through a resistor there is an RC time constant at play that lowers the rate at which voltage on the gate can change.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that but you'd have the same effect if the other end of the capacitor was at ground. Why is it located in-between the gate and drain then?

Comment: @kh.tf Because the gate doesn't know what ground is.  It is referenced to drain (or source).  It can prevent accidental turn-on at power-up when the capacitor is discharged.

Comment: @kh.tf - the gain of the MOSFET causes the rise to be linear when fed back from the drain. If it was connected to ground it would turn on more rapidly and with less control. Look up Miller integrator.

Comment: The RC circuit approach would definitely slow down turn on and turn off. I looked up the Miller Integrator as you said. So the benefit is that using that capacitor in the negative feedback path provides a more linear response (or change, as opposed to an exponential one provided by a simple RC circuit) when the GPIO pin is switched on and off. I recognize the difference now but I still don't understand what the benefit is. You said it can prevent accidental turn on during power up. So is its purpose is to give the uC enough time to configure its GPIO pins before switching?

Comment: No I'm wondering what state GPIO pins are in when a micro boots.

Comment: It's not so much the state of the I/O, it's just that a discharged capacitor will present a low voltage (ground) to the gate as the circuit comes up, so until the 3.3 V pullup can close it off the MOSFET will conduct for a split second on powerup.

Comment: I think you mean to say that the capacitor acts as a short on power up. I don't really follow your comment though, it doesn't appear to be any different that what I'm getting at.

Answer (score 0):

If you tied it to GND, then at the instant the 3.3 V is applied, it would hold the gate at GND and the FET would (temporarily) turn on.